# Sitecore 7 Search - Search.ashx

Tags: rest, lucene, sitecore

Anyone used the Sitecore 7 Lucene rest handler for Search (search.ashx)? I've seen it mentioned e.g. here: http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/04/Search-and-Indexing-Feature-List.aspx

Not sure whether it's a module or if it's built in. Any information on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /search.ashx that you are referring to is used by the SearchTab to perform the contentsearch action in the client. It can be either in a Bucket-item or in a regular search-tab.  You can leave parameters out and fiddle a bit with them. The response is a Json object.
However, you do need to be logged in to be able to use this handler. If you want to use something similar outside the client, take a look at the Sitecore Item Web Api.

The query looks like this:

```
http://website/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/Services/Search.ashx
?callback=jQuery110209093581063207239_1392643910752
&q%5B0%5D%5Btype%5D=text
&q%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=mysearchword
&q%5B0%5D%5Boperation%5D=must
&pageNumber=0
&type=Query
&pageSize=20
&version=1
&id=%7B5A0DDAAF-8438-4E8A-BA93-4F30212099D4%7D
&indexName=
&sc_content=master
&_=1392643910762
```

I searched for the word "mysearchword" .

EDIT:

here is the UrlDecoded version:

```
http://website/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/Services/Search.ashx
?callback=jQuery110209093581063207239_1392643910752
&q[0][type]=text
&q[0][value]=mysearchword
&q[0][operation]=must
&pageNumber=0
&type=Query
&pageSize=20
&version=1
&id={5A0DDAAF-8438-4E8A-BA93-4F30212099D4}
&indexName=
&sc_content=master
&_=1392643910762
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful. Can this be used outside of the sitecore client without being logged in? I'm looking to use this handler in an Ajax autocomplete search  scenario. If not, I'll have to write my own handler.

Comment: As far as i see it can't be used outside the client. If you want use something simulator outside the client, use the Item Web API.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick note, Search.ashx is an internal service for the UI to communicate with the search layer, as such it is subject to change at any time (ie in newer versions of the UI search etc) so it is best not to base any of your systems on it.

Have a look at `GetTermsByFieldName` which is part of the SearchContext classes (`LuceneSearchContext` / `SolrSearchContext`) to get terms for a particular field.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. Looks like a great place to start. Ian